# Incluir contador en nombre variable Python

Tags: python, lista, bucles

Tengo que crear listas de productos para unas columnas de un df de Pandas y luego combinarlas. Como hago para con un bucle crear dichas listas y no tener que hacerlo una por una.

Lo que estoy haciendo es:

```
products1 = df["Item 1"].unique().tolist()
products2 = df["Item 2"].unique().tolist()
products3 = df["Item 3"].unique().tolist()
products4 = df["Item 4"].unique().tolist()
products5 = df["Item 5"].unique().tolist()
products6 = df["Item 6"].unique().tolist()
products7 = df["Item 7"].unique().tolist()
products8 = df["Item 8"].unique().tolist()
products9 = df["Item 9"].unique().tolist()
```

Me parece una solución poco práctica y elegante.

Una vez tenga todas las listas de productos me gustaría combinarlas y estoy haciéndole de la misma manera cutre
`products = products1 + products2 + products3...`

Comment: Y si quieres trabajar con listas, por qué no usas directamente una lista en vez de cien variables diferentes? No hay diferencia entre trabajar con las listas que te devuelve el pandas y una lista que puedes crear tú. Es mucho mejor que utilizar variables *"sueltas"*

Answer (score 0):

podrías probar con este método para usar solamente una lista y no tener que crear una variable para cada producto como menciona Benito-B :

```
base_string = "Item "
final_list = []

items = 9




for i in range(items):
    item = i+1
    final_list.append(df.[base_string + str(item) ].unique().tolist())
```